# Каким образом можно получить доступ к переменной nickname?

Tags: c#, winforms

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно, чтобы вместе с сообщением выводился и никнейм, но в данной ситуации её не видно

Comment: Пожалуйста помните, что нужно вставлять код, а не скриншот кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это переменная из другого метода, ты её никак не получишь. Создай переменную в классе и уже к ней обращайся

```
class Test 
{
    public int i;
    public void Test(int a){ i = a; }
    public void Test2(){ int b; b = i; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Переменные, объявленные внутри блока кода имеют область видимости ограниченную этим блоком. Т.е. за пределами блока доступ к такой переменной невозможен. Блоками кода, например, является метод, тело цикла или условного оператора либо просто пара фигурных скобок.

Например, такой код **не** скомпилируется, потому что в одном и том же блоке мы задали две переменные с одним именем:

```
void foo() {
    bool a = true;
    bool a = false; // ошибка! повторное объявление переменной в том же блоке кода
}
```

а вот так скопмилируется, потому что мы разнесли объявления по разным блокам

```
void foo() { // блок кода метода
    // здесь переменная a будет недоступна
    { // блок1 
        bool a = true;
    }
    // здесь переменная a будет недоступна
    {// блок 2
        bool a = false;
    }
    // здесь переменная a будет недоступна
}
```

Таким образом, в вашем случае, нужно увеличить область видимости переменной nickname таким образом, чтобы она стала видна во всех необходимых методах. Самый просто способ сделать это - объявить переменную членом класса, которому данные методы принадлежат.